# Using DataContractSerializer to deserialize Xml with multiple collections

Tags: c#, datacontractserializer

I'm using DataContractSerializer to deserialize Xml, which has multiple collections.
The xml looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<collectionContents>
    <collection>
        <name>Folder1</name>
        <id>33399446</id>
        <contents>TestFolder1</contents>
    </collection>
    <collection>
      <name>Folder2</name>
      <id>566494</id>
      <contents>TestFolder2</contents>
    </collection>
    <file>
        <name>2012-08-24_171456.jpg</name>
        <id>33399624</id>
        <size>47612</size>
        <lastModified>2012-12-18T18:54:50.000-08:00</lastModified>
    </file>
    <file>
        <name>1033.ico</name>
        <id>33412726</id>
        <size>23246</size>
        <lastModified>2012-12-18T20:37:15.000-08:00</lastModified>
    </file>
</collectionContents>
```

And I created DataContractSerializer to deserialize the xml.

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
class Item
{
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string name;
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string id;
}

[DataContract(Name = "collection", Namespace = "")]
class Folder : Item
{
    [DataMember(Name = "contents")]
    public string contents;
}

[DataContract(Name = "file", Namespace = "")]
class File : Item
{
    [DataMember(Name = "size")]
    public long size;
    [DataMember(Name = "lastModified", Order = 3)]
    public string lastModified;
}

[CollectionDataContract(Name = "collectionContents", Namespace = "")]
class Folders : List<Folder>
{}

[CollectionDataContract(Name = "collectionContents", Namespace = "")]
class Files : List<File>
{}
```

I can use two DataContractSerializer to get the two collections folers & files.

```
DataContractSerializer folderSer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Folderes));
DataContractSerializer fileSer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Files));
```

But it needs deserialize twice, 
does anyone know that is there any way get two collection using only one DataContractSerializer?

I have tired below, but it returned count of folders/files is 0.

```
[DataContract(Name = "collectionContents", Namespace = "")]
class ItemCollectionList
{
    [DataMember(Name = "collection")]
    public Folders folders;     // Return count is 0;
    [DataMember(Name = "file")]
    public Files files;         // Return count is 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to include signature in your post - your user card is added automatically. Read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Can you *wrap* your `collection` and `file` elements in your XML with `folders` and `files` elements? (so that it better matches your `ItemCollectionList` type)